# How to query queryable state in Flink 1.4.0?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I find really very hard to understand the code in documentation.

```
QueryableStateClient client = new QueryableStateClient(tmHostname, proxyPort);

// the state descriptor of the state to be fetched.
ValueStateDescriptor<Tuple2<Long, Long>> descriptor =
        new ValueStateDescriptor<>(
          "average",
          TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Tuple2<Long, Long>>() {}),
          Tuple2.of(0L, 0L));

CompletableFuture<ValueState<Tuple2<Long, Long>>> resultFuture =
        client.getKvState(jobId, "query-name", key, BasicTypeInfo.LONG_TYPE_INFO, descriptor);

// now handle the returned value
resultFuture.thenAccept(response -> {
        try {
            Tuple2<Long, Long> res = response.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
});
```

How are `key` and `jobId` defined? There are also no test cases in `flink-queryable-state` module to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JobId can get from flink UI. `Overview` -> `Running Jobs` -> `Job ID`

[image: flink UI overview]

or you can get it by API.

```
JobGraph jobGraph = env.getStreamGraph().getJobGraph();

System.out.println("[info] Job ID: " + jobGraph.getJobID());
```

`Key` is what you specified to keyed stream. If you keyed a stream like below, the key should be a `Integer` type:

```
source.keyBy(new KeySelector<Tuple2<Integer, Long>, Integer>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8470749712274833552L;

        @Override
        public Integer getKey(Tuple2<Integer, Long> value) {
            return value.f0;
        }
    }).transform(
            "TestAggregatingOperator",
            BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
            new AggregatingTestOperator(aggrStateDescriptor)
    );
```

query code :

```
JobID jobID = JobID.fromHexString("ece5660c0e32a7d9780b8f24cd4fffc6");
    CompletableFuture<AggregatingState<Tuple2<Integer, Long>, String>> kvState = client.getKvState(jobID,
            "aggr-queryable",
            1, BasicTypeInfo.INT_TYPE_INFO,
            aggrStateDescriptor);
```

And I write a query demo at github. `testJob` method start a queryable state server. and `testQuery` method start a queryable state client.

https://github.com/liujiawinds/queryable-state-demo/blob/master/src/test/java/com/hansight/hanstreaming/Test.java

Answer (score 3):

`jobId` is the ID of the job that the queryable state belongs to. The `JobId` can be fetched from the `JobSubmissionResult` that is returned by `ExecutionEnvironment.execute()` or via Flink's REST API.

Queryable state is always keyed state which acts like a distributed hash map. The `key` is the key for which the value of the keyed state should be fetched.